# How to embedded ACE editor in html?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I recently need to embed Ace in my project, So I download the pre-build code from https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/ and I copied the code into my site from https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/editor.html where it lists how to embed Ace into a web page.

I copied that the src-min folder into my project. I changed the

```
<script src="src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

into

```
<script src="js/src-min/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

When I try to browse the web page in sandbox in [codeanywhere.com](https://codeanywhere.com/) (I also uploaded the src-min folder), I can only see the continent in  and there is no area for me to enter something new. Also, the code is in black and white.

What could I be doing wrong and what can I do to get Ace working properly?

Comment: What errors do you see in the browser console? there should be something about unable to load script, or ace is not defined.

Comment: No error is shown in the browser, just continent of <div>.

Comment: hmm, are you sure you look at the right place?, errors should be in console, _contents_ of div in the rendered page

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner please forgive my mistake. I saw the console and it says " because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set." So, I am trying to find where can I set the 'allow-scripts' permission. Thank you for answering.

Comment: That's likely a problem with codeanywhere, try running it locally or use another service.

Comment: Thank you! If mark your answer as solution will help you earn some marks (or points? I don't know, I just start overflow today), please move the comment into an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Yes it will help. Thank you. (did running locally help?)

Comment: the error shows in console is "Blocked script execution in 'https://codeanywhere.com/proxy/?XXXX' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set. ". So I click on the link, and see the running result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing in such cases is to look into browser console to see if something blocks loading the script.
As you commented, you have "frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set."
That's likely a problem with codeanywhere, try running it locally or use another service.